# How much reputation you need to have in order to create a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation

So how much reputation you need before you can create tags?

How to discuss whether or not a `tag` is valid?

Maybe I think it is but other members of this site will find it is not.

In this particular case:

I would like to create the tag `mercy` because mercy is one of the qualities of the Lord - He is very merciful but there many ways He has shown that mercy and everything related to that could be tagged as such.

the question below is one example where I would use it:

[Vishnu and His mercy in His hands](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15087/vishnu-and-his-mercy-in-his-hands)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) link in Help Center pages on this site i.e. Hinduism SE , One should have minimum of 150 reputation , to avail the privilege of creating and adding tags to the site. Also please check out rest the Help section to know more about other privileges and reputations.

Comment: that is correct I followed the link and went back to my original question and added the tag.

Answer (score 2):

> You need 1500 reputation now to create new tags.
>
> Keep in mind that many seemingly obvious tags may be named different
>   than you expect, to avoid ambiguity. For example, access seems like it
>   should be an obvious tag. However, it is not used because it was often
>   attached to questions covering both security permissions and a certain
>   notorious database platform. Instead, the tags authorization or
>   permissions should be used for the former, and ms-access for the
>   latter. These names avoid ambiguity, and there is zero additional
>   benefit to also using "access" in either case.
>
> Also remember that the point of tags on Stack Exchange is not to
>   summarize your question, but rather to sort it into a set of
>   well-defined categories. Tags are how your question connects to an
>   audience of users qualified to answer it. These users will have
>   certain tags marked as 'interesting' or subscribe to the rss feeds for
>   their tags. If you create a new tag, that tag is guaranteed to not
>   help attract any of those users.
>
> A good rule of thumb is to check the auto-suggest prompts when tagging
>   your question. Any tag with a number less than 10 (100 on Stack
>   Oveflow itself) after it's name is more than likely wrong. If you feel
>   you have a fairly common topic (take 'mssql' for example) and you see
>   a very small number for that tag, try an alternate name (like
>   'sql-server').

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4876/how-can-i-create-a-tag)